# SQL with multiple joins with same tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building a forum, and I have a problem with a SQL select with many joins. I want to show two images of different users in the same row.

The first image of the user is who wrote the topic, and the second image is of the user who last replied.

The query I build:

```
SELECT 
posts.*, users.photo, users.displayname FROM posts 
JOIN users ON(posts.useraid = users.id)
JOIN users ON(posts.lastreply = user.id)
WHERE forumid='$forumid' and type='post' ORDER BY `timee` DESC
```

- posts.lastreply = the ID of the last reply user.

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: you need to use different alias for each join...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify an alias for each table using the `AS` keyword:

```
SELECT posts.*, 
    u1.photo AS creatorPhoto, u1.displayname AS creatorName, 
    u2.photo AS replierPhoto, u2.displayname AS replierName
FROM posts 
JOIN users AS u1 ON(posts.useraid = u1.id)
JOIN users AS u2 ON(posts.lastreply = u2.id)
WHERE forumid= @forumid and type='post' 
ORDER BY `timee` DESC
```

Notice how I call each instance of the `users` table by a different name - `u1` and `u2`. Also notice how I have specified a column alias to distinguish between the two columns of the same name (e.g. `creatorPhoto` and `replierPhoto`). This way you can use the name as an index into a PHP associative array *a la* `$post['creatorPhoto']`.

*Yes, I've silently changed your inline variable to a parameter. Take it as a hint. :-D*

Comment: @user2124281 I've already added them to the SELECT clause in the query. Note the `u1.photo` and `u2.photo` for example.

Comment: works great, the only problem is that if "lastreply" = "" the posts not show.

Comment: @user2124281 You mean if there's no reply yet? In which case `lastreply` is `NULL` (which is *very different from* the empty string `''`)? Then you need a `LEFT JOIN` on the users table...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the lack of aliases in the `from` clause you may also have a problem with the `where` and `order by` clause.  You need to use aliases for the columns there.

I don't know where they come from, but something like:

```
WHERE posts.forumid='$forumid' and posts.type='post'
ORDER BY posts.`timee` DESC
```

Assuming all come from `posts`.

Answer (score 1):

you need an alias for this to work

```
SELECT 
posts.*, u1.photo, u1.displayname, u2.photo, u2.displayname FROM posts 
JOIN users u1 ON posts.useraid = u1.id
JOIN users u2 ON posts.lastreply = u2.id
WHERE forumid='$forumid' and type='post' ORDER BY `timee` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT posts.*, author.photo as author_photo, author.displayname as author+name,
       replier.photo as replier_photo, replier.displayname as replier_name
FROM posts 
  JOIN users author ON(posts.useraid = users.id)
  JOIN users replier ON(posts.lastreply = user.id)
WHERE forumid='$forumid' and type='post' ORDER BY `timee` DESC
```

Comment: Change JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN.  (Change both.)

Comment: works thanks dude! can i have your skype? for future problems?

Comment: @user2124281 - in general, it's best not to attempt to use volunteers here as a free private support channel. StackOverflow is useful precisely because all questions and answers are made public, and helpers here get 'rewarded' with reputation points. See my profile for a link to an article suggesting how to best use SO, which you may find helpful.